# Pegar texto de um input text

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte formulário

```
<form method="POST">

<input id="comentario" type="text" name="comentario" id="comentario">
<input type="submit" name="Comentar" value="Comentar" id="Comentar">

</form>
```

E preciso exibir na tela o que for digitado no input text. Também tenho esse trecho que verifica se o botao foi clicado (pretendo fazer minha logica aqui dentro)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Comentar'])){
        echo "botão foi clicado";

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: vc quer saber se o submit foi feito pelo botao? vao haver mais botoes? ou voce quer apenas que o submit seja feito pelo botao?

Comment: O que foi escrito no `<input>` do tipo `text`(o primeiro do html apresentado)  é acessível com `$_POST["comentario"]`. Qual é a questão especificamente?

Comment: @Isac ela quer recuperar o value do button, nao do input...  Ha necessidade de submit? poderia fazer com jquery e enviar via $.post? poderia formular melhor sua necessidade, seus recursos pq de repente seu caminho nao seja a melhor forma...

Comment: Pegar o `value` de um `submit` ? Com que finalidade ? Nunca muda é sempre igual. Parece-me um problema XY

Comment: Acredito que o titulo da pergunta esteja equivocada. O que ele quer é recuperar o value do que foi digitado no `type="text`  pois ninguém que eu saiba consegue digitar algo em um input submit

Comment: Opa, errei mesmo, é input text. Tem como editar?

Comment: Logo abaixo da linha ` echo "botão foi clicado";` coloque  `echo $_POST['comentario'];`

Comment: editei pra você

Comment: @Deyci você quer enviar via *Ajax* ? Pois se for apenas enviar via *POST* não a necessidade do *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para receber o envio via `POST`, você utiliza a variável `$_POST["name_do_input"]`

```
<form method="POST">

<input id="comentario" type="text" name="comentario" id="comentario">
<input type="submit" name="Comentar" value="Comentar" id="Comentar">

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Comentar']))
{   echo "botão foi clicado"."<br/>";
    $texto_digitado = $_POST["comentario"];
    echo  "Texto digitado: ".$texto_digitado;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form action="" method="post">
     Escolha um botão
      <button name="Comentar" type="submit" value="escolha1">HTML</button>
      <button name="Comentar" type="submit" value="escolha2">CSS</button>
    </form>
```

Aqui, se recuperar o valor de 'Comentar' poderá manipular, por exemplo, se ele não for vazio, já significa que algum for clicado, ou pode verificar qual foi...
 Caso o submit seja feito com o enter em um input o valor será vazio.

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['Comentar'])){
        echo "um botão foi clicado";
      if($_POST['Comentar] =='escolha1'){
         echo "clicou em HTML";
       }
    }
 ?>
```